# ANDROID,JAVA:Getting duplicate results with cursor and loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, cursor

I am a noob in java but I have some knowledge of c++, so I made loops with that consideration.
I am trying to get data from two arrays containing names of tables from a DB. If any one element from any table is equal to the element of another, both  names of both tables get saved in another array. This happens until the arrays end. Now by some problem each cursor contains same table many times but I think I took care of it.
Now by using below logic I should be getting one or two distinct pairs of tables but instead I am getting same pairs again and again. I am changing loops order and logic many times but this formation at least gives result. 
I think the problem is logical instead of syntax. Where did I go wrong?

My code is:

```
    int maa;

    for (int i = 0; i < ArraySource.size(); i++) {

        // cursor for source

        Cursor sourceCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + ArraySource.get(i) + "';", null);
        int sourceIndex = sourceCursor.getColumnIndex("Stop");

        for (int ii = 0; ii < ArrayDest.size(); ii++) {

            // counter for finding match
            maa=0;


            Cursor destCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + ArrayDest.get(ii) + "';", null);
            int destIndex = destCursor.getColumnIndex("Stop");

            sourceCursor.moveToFirst();
            String nameSource = sourceCursor.getString(sourceIndex);
            destCursor.moveToFirst();
            String nameDest = destCursor.getString(destIndex);

            // data is repeated many times in the cursor, so this is hack to take the first result and check with every result
            // so if match is found loop is broken

            // But to do that first result should be taken out of loop, hence the following
            // First result of first cursor checking with first result of second cursor

            if (nameSource.equals(nameDest)){

                IndirectArray1.add(ArraySource.get(i));
                IndirectArray2.add(ArrayDest.get(ii));
                maa=1;

            }else {

                //checking with all results of second cursor
                for (destCursor.moveToNext(); !destCursor.isAfterLast(); destCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    if(nameDest.equals(destCursor.getString(destIndex))){

                        break;
                    }

                    if (nameSource.equals(destCursor.getString(destIndex))) {

                        IndirectArray1.add(ArraySource.get(i));
                        IndirectArray2.add(ArrayDest.get(ii));
                        maa=1;
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            // condition for running nexr for loop above logic is used in following loop
            if(maa ==0){

                MsMoot:
                for (sourceCursor.moveToNext(); !sourceCursor.isAfterLast(); sourceCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    destCursor.moveToFirst();

                    if (nameSource.equals(sourceCursor.getString(sourceIndex))) {

                        break;

                    }

                    if (sourceCursor.getString(sourceIndex).equals(destName)) {

                        IndirectArray1.add(ArraySource.get(i));
                        IndirectArray2.add(ArrayDest.get(ii));
                        break;

                    }else {

                        for (destCursor.moveToNext(); !destCursor.isAfterLast(); destCursor.moveToNext()) {

                            if (destCursor.getString(destIndex).equals(nameDest)) {

                                break;

                            }

                            if (sourceCursor.getString(sourceIndex).equals(destCursor.getString(destIndex))) {

                                IndirectArray1.add(ArraySource.get(i));
                                IndirectArray2.add(ArrayDest.get(ii));
                                break MsMoot;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            // closing cursors
            }destCursor.close();

        }sourceCursor.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like infinity loop. You are getting duplicated rows because you are trying to loop everything, and many times. In the result you are getting first row of each table many times, and then some value is marked as the same some times. Cursor make an query for a specific table, and store data. Now you should read all data, and store it in more human way. Then check, if stored data is equals. Here is sample code.

@edit


Now, for each table stored inside ArraySource list, you are calling query for every table inside ArrayDest list, then I put foreach loop, which checking does each String from firstList equals inside secondList. This should work properly.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArraySource.size(); i++) {
                List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
                Cursor sourceCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + ArraySource.get(i) + "';", null);

                if(sourceCursor != null) {
                    if(sourceCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String a = sourceCursor.getString(0);
                            firstList.add(a);
                        } while(sourceCursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                }

                sourceCursor.close();

                for (int j = 0; j < ArrayDest.length; j++) {

                    Cursor destCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + ArrayDest.get(j) + "';", null);

                    if (destCursor != null) {
                        if (destCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                String b = destCursor.getString(0);
                                secondList.add(b);
                            } while (destCursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                    }
                    destCursor.close();

                    for (String one : firstList) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < secondList.size(); k++) {
                            String two = secondList.get(k);
                            if (one.equals(two)) {
                                //make your logic here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: As per my understanding, this loop will check first result of firstlist with all results of secondlist, then second result of firstlist with all results of secondlist and so on. Should I put an extra loop for all results of firstlist, above the j loop?

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the logic. your solution has saved me 100+ lines overall.